# wpf binding list inside class not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

When I want to bind an ObservableCollection of strings to the UI. I do this:

```
ObservableCollection<string> myStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
myStrings.Add("hello");
myItemsControl.ItemsSource = myStrings;
```

Then when I add/remove elements from that list, the UI updates.

However, when I add the ObservableCollection into another class the binding does not update:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> myStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

TestClass myTestClass = new TestClass();
myTestClass.myStrings.Add("hello");
myItemsControl.ItemsSource = myTestClass.myStrings;
```

The binding works first time but does not update when I add/remove items. Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to bind to a field, not a property. Change your class to

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        myString = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> myStrings {get; set;}
}
```

and it should work as expected.